# NSTextView with clear background have phantom text

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I want to implement a textview with transparent background to show subtitles.

When I set Window backgroundColor = .clear, disable NSTextView draw background, then I change NSTextView.string as you can see in the following picture, **previous text retain in the background**
[phantom text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzbMH.png)

How can I clear the background text (Foo1245 in the image background) when change NSTextView.string ?

POC code is here [POC](https://github.com/yalarmorghulis/SingleView)

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Editable transparent NSTextField text appears with white highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654496/editable-transparent-nstextfield-text-appears-with-white-highlight).

Answer (score 1):

Did you read: [How to implement NSTextFinderClient protocol in NSTextView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010643/how-to-implement-nstextfinderclient-protocol-in-nstextview-in-swift) ?

Are you calling `textFinder.noteClientStringWillChange()` or `textFinder.performAction(.HideFindInterface)` when you change the `NSTextView.string` ?